# Monogame on Windows Phone 8 wrong backbuffer size

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, monogame

I have created a MonoGame project from Windows Phone 8.0 template. When I deploy my app (that should show only blue screen), backbuffer size is wrong (it is too small). When I changed Grid to DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid, backbuffer size is fine, but my project is not in landscape - it is in portrait. How can I fix it?

I use lumia 635 with windows mobile 10.

Answer (score 0):

In your Game constructor, just specify the backbuffer size you want to use. For example:

```
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}
```

Comment: Hi i forgot about this post, but i fix it, specyfing size in Game constructor doesn't work, i cheked it first.

To repair that, i set GamePage width and height (it was null), it works, and now backbuffer size is correct. :)